# Pandas function to run stats on Categories for Date

Tags: python, dataframe, function, datetime, group-by

I am trying to run stats on a ticket system.
Currently I have been copy and pasting the code and changing it for every day. I want to be have a function that I can feed in the df and get out another df with the created and closed stats per category for every date.

Here is a sample of the df
[-image of sample of the df-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azZoS.png)
(Apologies that images aren't embeded I am new to stack overflow and i haven't been granted those permissions yet)

There are 22 unique categories and I want to run this so it shows me the number of tickets opened and closed for each working day for 2 months.

Can someone help me write with as a function that reads in a pandas df and outputs a df with the stats.

```
#Closed 14 April
Apr141=df[(df['Status']=='Resolved')&(df['Close Date']=="2023-04-14T00:00:00.000000000")] #no that closed on Monday
Apr14_1=pd.DataFrame(Apr141.groupby(['Category'],dropna=False).count().drop(['Status','Close Date','Duration'], axis=1).rename(columns={"Date": "14 Apr Closed"}) )
#Open 14 April
Apr142=df[(df['Date']=="2023-04-14T00:00:00.000000000")]  # #no that new on Monday
Apr14_2=Apr142.groupby(['Category'],dropna=False).count().drop(['Status','Close Date','Duration'], axis=1).rename(columns={"Date": "14 Apr New"})

#Closed 13 April
Apr131=df[(df['Status']=='Resolved')&(df['Close Date']=="2023-04-13T00:00:00.000000000")] #no that closed on Monday
Apr13_1=pd.DataFrame(Apr131.groupby(['Category'],dropna=False).count().drop(['Status','Close Date','Duration'], axis=1).rename(columns={"Date": "13 Apr Closed"}) )
#Open 13 April
Apr132=df[(df['Date']=="2023-04-13T00:00:00.000000000")]  # #no that new on Monday
Apr13_2=Apr132.groupby(['Category'],dropna=False).count().drop(['Status','Close Date','Duration'], axis=1).rename(columns={"Date": "13 Apr New"})


a1 = pd.concat([Apr13_2, Apr13_1, Apr14_2, Apr14_1], axis=1).fillna(0)
```

This is my attempt of writing the function

```
def f(df):

  for i in df['Date']:
    if df['Status'] == 'Resolved':
      x1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Category'],dropna=False).count().drop(['Status','Close Date','Duration'], axis=1).rename(columns={"Date": i }) )
    else:
      x2 = df.groupby(['Category'],dropna=False).count().drop(['Status','Close Date','Duration'], axis=1).rename(columns={"Date": i})
    a1 = pd.concat([x1,x2])
  return a1
```

What I want is for the df to printed out like this. Where it shows how many tickets were created and closed per category for each Date.
[-image of Manually generated stats chart-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAG7S.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would have helped a lot if you provided a example of the Dataframe df. I suppose you read some bit about pivot or pivot tables since I expect that this may help to solve your task:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Here is a example for a pivot table with some dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dictionary of data
data = {
    'Date': ['2023-04-01', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-03'],
    'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'Status': ['Open', 'Closed', 'Open', 'Open'],
    'Close Date': ['2023-04-02', '2023-04-02', '', ''],
    'Duration': [1, 0, '', '']
}
# create a dataframe from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create a pivot table
pivot_df = df.pivot(index='Category', columns=['Date', 'Status'], values='Duration')
pivot_df = pivot_df.fillna(0)

# print the pivot table
print(pivot_df)
```

The output than looks like this:

```
Date     2023-04-01 2023-04-02      2023-04-03
Status         Open     Closed Open       Open
Category                                      
A                 1        NaN  NaN        NaN
B               NaN          0  NaN        NaN
C               NaN        NaN             NaN
D               NaN        NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Hi apologies for not giving a sample of the df. I've attached a screenshot now.

Comment: That looks great! Is there a way of doing this if the data is read in from a csv file?

Answer (score 0):

This is close to what was produced manually. The two functions need to be combined to have the closed and open stats together

```html
def closed(frame):
  frame = frame[['Category', 'Close Date']].sort_values('Close Date')
  b = pd.DataFrame( df['Category'].unique() ).rename(columns={ 0 : "Categories" }).set_index('Categories')

  for date in frame['Close Date'].unique():
    a = frame[( frame['Close Date'] == date )].groupby(['Category']).count()
    a.rename(columns={'Close Date': date}, inplace=True)
    b = pd.concat([b,a],axis=1).fillna(0)
  return b

def opened(frame):
  frame = frame[['Category', 'Date']].sort_values('Date')
  b = pd.DataFrame( df['Category'].unique() ).rename(columns={ 0 : "Opened Categories" }).set_index('Opened Categories')

  for date in frame['Date'].unique():
    a = frame[( frame['Date'] == date )].groupby(['Category']).count()
    b = pd.concat([b,a],axis=1).fillna(0).rename(columns={'Date': date}, inplace=True)
  return b

opened(df)
closed(df)
```

This is as far as I've got:

```html
def f(frame):
  frame = frame[['Category', 'Date', 'Close Date']]
  b = pd.DataFrame( df['Category'].unique() ).rename(columns={ 0: "Categories" } )
  frame = frame.drop('Close Date',axis=1)
  for date in frame['Date']:
    
    a = frame[( frame['Date'] == date )].groupby(['Category']).count()
    a.rename(columns={'Date': date}, inplace=True)
    #b = pd.concat(
  return a




f(df)
```

The only issue is it is only printing out the final date and I want it to append on concat every date

Answer (score 0):

Thanks at least for a screenshot of your data. I used Google to extract the text and created this set of dummy data. I also modfied four fields since there was only on date (`2023-02-27`) and one type of status (`resolved`):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Category': ['Access Issues', 'Access Issues', 'Access Issues', 'Access Issues', 'sues-Missing', 'sues-Missing', 'sues-Missing'],
    'Status': ['Resolved', 'Resolved', 'Resolved', 'Resolved', 'Open', 'Resolved', 'Open'],
    'Date': ['2023-02-27', '2023-02-27', '2023-02-27', '2023-02-27', '2023-02-27', '2023-02-28', '2023-02-28'],
    'Close Date': ['2023-02-28', '2023-03-03', '2023-03-01', '2023-03-06', '2023-03-02', '2023-03-02', '2023-03-07'],
    'Duration': ['11:55:00', '36:55:00', '20:55:00', '46:13:00', '31:04:00', '31:27:00', '56:29:00']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'Date' and 'Close Date' columns to datetime objects
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Close Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Close Date'])

# Create the pivot table
pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index='Category', columns=['Date', 'Status'], values=['Duration'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

print(pivot_df)
```

The output then looks like this:

```
                Duration                             
Date          2023-02-27          2023-02-28         
Status              Open Resolved       Open Resolved
Category                                             
Access Issues          0        4          0        0
sues-Missing           1        0          1        1
```

Comment: That looks great! Is there a way of doing this if the data is read in from a csv file?

Comment: You can read a csv into a dataframe like this: `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')`. You might need to change the separator accordingly to your file.